# Using Raster Calculator Con(isnull) with ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, con

[image]I am using ArcMap 10.4.1 and the Raster Calculator to subtract polygons of clouds, land etc from my DEM. I use the statement:

```
con(isnull, Cloud, DEM)
```

and set the processing extent to environments of input because otherwise I do not get me whole DEM back.

Every time I do that though, the extracted cells do not match with the extent of my polygons anymore. There is always a shift of a few meters.
Cell size is same for both.

Where is the problem?

Comment: If I do not set extent to Uniof in inputs, the extent extracted is the same as the polygon

Comment: Add a supporting screenshot.

Comment: There are no such functions as `con` or `isnull`, your expression should never have even been able to run.  If you're going to ask questions here, post exactly  what you did, don't approximate. There is `Con` and `IsNull` however. Note `IsNull` is a *function* and you pass it something to test for null values. Your expression should look like `Con(IsNull(DEM), Cloud, DEM)`. Your cloud polygons are getting converted where the centre of a pixel is overlapped by the polygon.  You can't mask part of a pixel.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid nulls/blank cells, you may also want to check that the layer projections and units of Cloud and DEM match. Setting a snap raster also helps make the cells line up properly.